# students whose majors are not listed?

Tags: xpath

```
<univ>
 <student>
 <id>1</id>
 <major>cs</major>
 </student>
 <student>
 <id>2</id>
 </student>
  .... 
</univ>
```

How to find student ID's not having any major?
So the output should be 2.

Guess the one mentioned is wrong.
/univ/student[not(major)]/id/text()

Comment: How is this data stored? In an XML file? As HTML? What technology are you using to retrieve the data? DOM? Xpath? E4X?

Comment: In XML file, Using Xpath

Comment: What's the problem with that XPath? Looks correct to me, unless I understand the requirement wrong..

Comment: Is the mentioned Xpath is correct? I'm new to Xpath and don't know the answer, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Yes: http://xpatheval.apphb.com/FF1t12W_8